# Visual Studio C# - App opens a cmd in background

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Since I created a MSI installer with Visual Studio (I removed it from my solution) - since then, my application opens a command prompt in the background when I run the application.

Screenshot: http://cl.ly/6EP2

Why? How can i ditch it?

Thank you very much

Best Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

project explorer -> rightclick your project -> properties -> application tab -> change "console application" to "windows application" (i've got only the german localized version here, so maybe it's labled different)